# Versioned file stated as unversioned

Tags: git

Just started using git, so please don't blame me.

Using command line git right now. After cloning an existing repo from Git-Hub on my home machine, I have an issue that all files that I modify are stated as "untracked" - Even tho when I just pulled them from the repo.

I think this is because I have the following structure on my office machine:

```
folder\repo_content_here
```

And on my home machine I have the following:

```
folder\repo_name_from_git_hub\repo_content_here
```

How can I fix this issue? What I actually do is to just add the file again and again before pushing to GitHub.

**Update**

When I do git pull it looks like this:

[image]

When I modify a file inside my repo and after that do "git status" I get this:

[image]

I am wondering why I have to add the file again and again even tho I got it in my repo already. I just want to do `git commit` and `git push` after I changed files that are already in my repo. I dont wan't to add them again (As I said, they are already added from my point of view..).

This behavior started when I cloned the GitHub repo on my home machine. I did not had this issue before. What have I done wrong? How can i fix it? Just clone again maybe?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you provide some additional info? E.g. run `git status` before you modify anything, modify a tracked file and run `git status` again.

Comment: How exactly did you pull the repo? I suspect that may be you did it incorrectly

Comment: golergka I just did "git pull". Is it wrong? I am on master branch. Just doing the simplest possible git commit -> git push -> git pull thing. aronisstav update above

Comment: *As I said, they are already added from my point of view ..)* Well, in Git's point of view, they are not. Anyway are you aware that the files listed as changed and untracked are not the same file? 1 is 'changed' because it was already in the repo and you changed it (obviously). The other is untracked because it looks like some sort of temporary file that should never be pushed in a Git repo. These kind of files are usually put in the .gitignore so they aren't shown by `git status`. *I dont wan't to add them again* Well, you have to or Git won't know what to commit

Comment: Tim Castelijns - Sure thing for the temporary file, yes. But as I said I redo add "untracked filename here" over and over again. When I do a new pull after i added, commited, pushed I have the same issue again. That can't be right.

Comment: @Grrbrr404: As long as *.odt#-files aren't added to your [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore.html), git will everytime show that file as untracked since open office creates it again with every backup.

Comment: And be aware, coworkers may unintentially add files to the index, based on missing gitignore-directives! How to ignore already tracked files may be read in the manual - see the link in the previous comment.

Comment: @Grrbrr404: How do you add them, what is the content of your `.gitignore` and what does `git status` tell you after the "add"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering why I have to add the file again and again even tho I got it in my repo already.

`git add` actually adds specific content.  When you change a tracked file, git notices there's new content at that path and reminds you to add it if you want the changed content in the next commit.

> I just want to do git commit and git push after I changed files that are already in my repo. I dont wan't to add them again.

You and me both.  Usually.  What you're after is `git commit -a`, meaning "add any changed content in tracked files and then commit".

Answer (score 2):

First of all, git tracks every file - and only files - which are in its index. With other words, to make git versioning a file it **must** be in its index.

Current files may not be in the index for two reasons, 1) it was created since the last git-operation and therefore is untracked or 2) it was changed and is namely known to git (why its now flagged as modified) but different from the existing state of the file.

### Untracked files

Untracked files are always somehow new to git. It tells you that new content appeared to your repo. And you may now decide if git tracks it (with `git add`) or should ignore it from now on (adding it to the `.gitignore`-file).

> gitignore is often used to hold temporary contents (like build-data, backup-files and so on) to prevent that coworkers working-directory get polluted with unecessary stuff.

### Modified files

Files you modified are always stated to be `modified:` as long as they are not packed into a commit in your repository.

Having an issue with your directory-structure is unlikely since you "cloned" from github and git usually prepares everything fine on your local machine. And the directory-structures on all the different clients and/or servers are completely independent from one point of view: the root directory of your repository, which always holds the `.git/` hidden repository-directory.

I think you may have a wrong sight on the basic git-workflow, which is:

1. Modify your files (they are now `modified` but not `not staged for commit`)
2. Stage all necessary files (with [`git add`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html)) for the next commit (they are now `modified` and listed as `Changes to be committed`)
3. Commit your changes (with [`git commit`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html)). If all modified files where successfully packed into a snapshot, git states that there is `nothing to commit, working directory clean`

These commits reside in your local repository until you ask git to push them to a remote. To do so you usually pull changes from the remote first, to check for conflicts and after that push your changes to the remote.

To check the status of your repository you may (and will) use [`git status`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html) between the different steps.

This is much better (and in more detail) explained in [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#The-Three-States)

Another helpful resource is the interactive [Git Cheat Sheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html).

Comment: `Modify your files (they are now modified..)` apparently in OP's case they are not, and the question is why

Comment: He's wondering that "all files that [he] modif[ies] are stated as 'untracked'" which sounds like the basic workflow may not have understood correctly. But i should clarify that - you're right.